# Additional Data types (such as Unsigned SmallInt, Datetime and Decimal) in Swift Vapor/Fluent Model?

Tags: mysql, swift, vapor

I'm trying to create a `Model` with Vapor, and in the `prepare` method, I can't seem to figure out how to add some data types into the statement.

Looking into the Vapor source code, there seems to be some data types that can be stored:

```
extension Schema {
    /**
        Various types of fields
        that can be used in a Schema.
    */
    public struct Field {
        public var name: String
        public var type: DataType
        public var optional: Bool

        public enum DataType {
            case id
            case int
            case string(length: Int?)
            case double
            case bool
            case data
        }

        public init(name: String, type: DataType, optional: Bool = false) {
            self.name = name
            self.type = type
            self.optional = optional
        }
    }
}
```

So Data Types like Int, String (`VARCHAR`), Double, Bool and Data (`BLOB`) can be stored, but I can't find the ones I'm looking for, specifically:

- Unsigned `SMALLINT` (`UInt16`)
- `DATETIME`
- `DECIMAL` ([The MySQL Decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), NOT Double or Float)

How would I make these?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the feature is not present in Vapor / Fluent, however it's [in the making](https://github.com/vapor/fluent/pull/106/files/6b2880d5c0f358656dfc3a45a248e3b192cd877e#diff-105537c8b8a069018bd1aff928304355).

Here's [the issues page of Vapor regarding `DATETIME`](https://github.com/vapor/fluent/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=datetime)